# How do you change the UniObjects.NET mode from using ... to using [ and ]?

Tags: .net, u2, unidata, uniobjects

How do you programmatically change the UniObjects.NET mode from using ... to using [ and ] when using the query command?

Comment: Sorry, I've been on my honeymoon and just got back. I deleted my answer as it was incorrect. I don't believe you can. Do you have a specific reason you must do this (aka ... causes you issue 'x')?

Comment: No problem. Congratulations by the way! All our UniData programmers know the [ and ] syntax and other syntax differences. I would like it to be similar to what they already know and use on a daily basis so that when they use it in UniObjects.NET they don't have to relearn the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is driven by the flavour of the account to which you are connecting.  You could change it programmatically by executing a TCL command to change the flavour via UniObjects.

Comment: and what would that TCL command be? complete UniObjects code would be helpful.